# Posting link with space in url

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

I have a link that has a space in the URL

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread Safety
                                                                                          ^
```

When I post it bare, it misses the word safety, for obvious reasons:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread Safety

---

When I do the inline syntax, it thinks it's HTML

```
<https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread Safety>
```

---

When I do this syntax it doesn't work

[test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread Safety)

```
[test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread Safety)
```

---

When I do this syntax it doesn't work

```
[test][1]


 [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread Safety
```

[test][1]

[1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread Safety

---

When I put it in an `a` tag, the space is converted to `%20`

[Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread%20Safety)

```
<a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread Safety">Test</a>
```

---

When I put in `%20` or `+` in for the space, the hash isn't resolved.

How can I insert this url?

Comment: @BSMP i tried escaping it but my browser is treating it as a separate hash.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize the system was doing the same thing, re: the second answer.

Comment: Have you tried `#Anchor_9` yet?

Comment: @mario the hash isn't recognized.

Comment: For me the anchor icon next to that heading links to `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_9`. [Fragments should be percent-encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679500/how-to-encode-space-in-the-fragment-identifier-in-a-url), so `%20` should be used in the anchor name, if it were `Thread Safety`. How did you obtain the link?

Comment: That’s not a legal URL, *unescaped spaces are not permitted*. Replace the space with `%20`. Your browser URL bar is not normative here, that’s a limited context with *just the URL* and they can be more flexible.

Comment: The same applies to the parentheses. Those must also be escaped, with `%28` and `%29`.  I think; they are reserved characters and must be encoded in those parts of a URL where they have special meaning.

Comment: If the hash isn’t resolved when properly encoded then that’s a bug *on the Microsoft website* in that their JS code doesn’t decode the hash value first. This is not a bug on Stack Overflow’s side, markdown or otherwise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it doesn’t work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hashes are handled client side with ‘<a name=“...”>’

Comment: Ironically enough, in Mobile Chrome on my iPhone the url `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread%20Safety` works, while using a space does not. I used the contents menu to jump to that section and the URL hash produced contained the escaped space.

Comment: @Daniel: I know how hashes work. You don’t *have* to have a named target, JS code can also read the value from the URL and act on it. If there was an actual target name then `%20` would just work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so maybe it’s a chrome bug?

Comment: Perhaps. Browser or JS implementation. Not a SO bug however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well I’m not sure how people are supposed to link to something from the address bar then

Comment: I wonder about that too sometimes, when you get UTF-8 bytes in the URL shown decoded. But I’m most cases I’ve seen copying the whole URL produce the right URL.

Answer (score 6):

Not the first time this has come up relating to MSDN (can't find the others off hand but they've been recent). As far as I know, you can report this to them and they'll fix the anchor so that they work as expected.

But, spaces in links *have* to be encoded. There might be some client-side voodoo happening on their side so that natural search translates to page anchors (I think that's actually what's going on), but the actual permanent resource location (e.g. the URL) *has* to be properly encoded in order for any browser to use it properly.

I'd let them know about it, as I believe others are doing, they fix it once alerted to it if I recall correctly from the last time this came up.

In the meantime, I'd just link to the page itself and let people know to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (or whatever triggers on-page search) and let them know what to put in there .. and remember to check on it a few weeks after you report it so you can edit it in properly? Wonky, I know, I wish I had a better suggestion, but there's nothing we could do on our end that would make it work.

Comment: (that feeling when you _know_ you just helped someone with this exact same thing and a search even with `deleted:all` selected yields nothing here or on MSE and then you start wondering what other site it could have possibly been ...)

Comment: Feature request: search your own posts network wide?